# Helicon ReWrite rule for static pages

Tags: .htaccess

What is the Helicon rewrite cond /rule i need to use to redirect this one static page:

/page.asp?pg=ovens

to

http://www.rdo.co.uk/products.asp?id=134&rs=1&sel_supplier=280

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /page\.asp\?pg=ovens\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ http://www.rdo.co.uk/products.asp?id=134&rs=1&sel_supplier=28 [R,L]
```

It will check the parameter after `pg` and if it is `ovens` then it will redirect it to the page you specified, if it doesn't then it will skip it.